# How to enable emmet for .ejs file in lazy nvim

Tags: neovim, emmet

i want to enable the abbrevation in `.ejs` file in nvim (lazy vim). I have installed the `emmet` but it is not working in `.ejs` file.
Here is my config

```
return {
  {
    "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
    ---@class PluginLspOpts
    opts = {
      ---@type lspconfig.options
      servers = {
        emmet_ls = {
          filetypes = {
            "html",
            "typescriptreact",
            "javascriptreact",
            "css",
            "sass",
            "scss",
            "less",
            "javascript",
            "typescript",
            "markdown",
            "ejs",
          },
          init_options = {
            html = {
              options = {
                -- For possible options, see: https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/src/config.ts#L79-L26
                ["bem.enabled"] = true,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run `:set ft?` in a mjs file to learn its actual file type then put it in the config